# Preference cannot cast java.lang.boolean to String

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have the following Preference class:

```
public class AppPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private SharedPreferences appPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
    private Mediator mediator;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
    private User user;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //---load the preferences from an XML file---
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        this.appPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        this.mediator = (Mediator) getApplication();    
        this.prefEditor = appPrefs.edit();
        this.user = mediator.getUser();
        setPreferences();
        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                // Implementation
                updatePreference(key);
                Toast.makeText(AppPreferencesActivity.this,
                        "Information updated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        appPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

    } 
    private void setPreferences(){
        prefEditor.putString("nameEdit", user.getName() + " "+user.getLastName());
        prefEditor.putString("streetEdit", user.getStreetName());
        prefEditor.putString("streetNumberEdit", ""+user.getStreetNr());
        prefEditor.putString("emailEdit", user.getEmail());
        prefEditor.commit();
        preferenceAddSummary();
    }
    public boolean checkEmailStatus(){
        return appPrefs.contains("emailEdit");
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void preferenceAddSummary() {
        for (Entry<String, ?> key : appPrefs.getAll().entrySet()) {
            findPreference(key.getKey()).setSummary(appPrefs.getString(key.getKey(), "Not yet entered")); 
// this is where im getting the error

            }
```

However when i run this i get the following

> Cannot cast Java.lang.boolean to Java.lang.String

I get this error at the loop im calling to setSumary can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

Full stackTrace in text:

```
   05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.konkurrencesigner/com.example.konkurrencesigner.AppPreferencesActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.example.konkurrencesigner.AppPreferencesActivity.preferenceAddSummary(AppPreferencesActivity.java:55)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.example.konkurrencesigner.AppPreferencesActivity.setPreferences(AppPreferencesActivity.java:47)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.example.konkurrencesigner.AppPreferencesActivity.onCreate(AppPreferencesActivity.java:28)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-02 02:28:15.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Show us the full stack trace please

Comment: Uploaded print of stack trace - Edit just noticed the size updating image

Comment: Why are you uploading an image? Just copy paste the stack trace..

Comment: To save others time searching on this error, it'll also happen if you accidentally use a `CheckBoxPreference` instead of an `EditTextPreference`, at least for a numeric input type. Upon calling `addPreferencesFromResource()`, Android only throws the unhelpful error that it can't convert a string to a boolean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It obviously that some prefs are checked and only return boolean value.
So you cannot use this directly.

```
for (Entry<String, ?> key : appPrefs.getAll().entrySet()) {
    findPreference(key.getKey()).setSummary(appPrefs.getString(key.getKey(), "Not yet entered"));
}
```

I think maybe you should use like that:

```
for (Entry<String, ?> key : appPrefs.getAll().entrySet()) {
    Object result = key.getValue();
    if (result instanceof Boolean) {
        //handle boolean
    } else if (result instanceof String) {
        //handle String
    }
    findPreference(key.getKey()).setSummary(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response however all of my preferences is editText is it possible that by default the map contains a boolean?

Comment: Are there any other preferences you are using in other file? If you write a PreferenceActivity as settings, all values will be saved in  in DefaultSharedPreferences at default. You can pull the xml file from device to check all preference. The xml file will be saved in data/data/yourpakcages/shared_prefs/yourpackage_preferences.xml in your device.

Answer (score 23):

I was getting the same error. I went and deleted App's data and my app doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: This solved it for me too. I mistakenly saved the wrong type to my saved preferences during development and it continued to crash my app when I implemented the preference with the correct type.

Comment: This fixed the crash for me as well. What happened was I was following an online tutorial, so the keys of the preferences were named generically, like "key1" and "key2". I switched their types, but kept the keys and that's when the crash started. A clearing of the apps data allowed development to continue.

Comment: Solved my problem tooo, thanks alot for saving lots of time

Comment: That may be the case, but did you test what happens if you change the offending value again?

Comment: Nope, I have not.

Answer (score 7):

I had this error too. It happined when i first had a checkbox preference, then used the same name for a list preference, but on my phone in the preferences it was still saved as a boolean and it tried to load that into my list.

fix: clear app data

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too, and couldn't figure out why. I think it's because I added a new preference and tried running the app again. I uninstalled the app, then ran it again with the new preferences, and it worked. Maybe it needed a full wipe to reset the sharedpreferences file.